# How to find the number of terms in the following geometric progression $2^0+2+2^2 + ... + 2^{2n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

According to book the answer is: $2n+1$.

I have no idea where it came from. I have tried to use the n-th term of a geometric sequence formula, but without any luck. Maybe  I am just tired - any help would be greatly appreciated.

$$
2^{2n}=2^{n-1}
$$

By the way, given sequence is just a numerator that is part of a limit exercise.

> **Update:** The above $n$, as I said, is part of the limit exercise, where $n\rightarrow\infty$. I have confused the $n$ from $\lim$ with then $n$ from the n-th term of a geometric sequence formula.

$$\begin{align}
2^{2n}=2^{k-1}\\
2n=k-1\\
k = 2n + 1
\end{align}$$

where $k$ represents the number of terms. Duck debugging works as always and the Earth spins again.

Comment: the exponents are $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,2n-1,2n.$ So there are $2n+1$ separate terms.

Comment: Can I prove it using some calculations?

Comment: @KamilLatosinski  see the answer below

Comment: The exponents are $0,1,2,\dots,2n$. Add $1$ to each exponent and you get $1,2,3,\dots, 2n+1$.  Can you see now why there are $2n+1$ terms?

Answer (score 3):

There is $2n-0+1$ terms since the sum start at $1= 2^0$ and end at $2^{2n}$

In general 
if you have $$u_k+\cdots +u_m$$
then the number of term is $\color{blue}{m-k+1}.$